SwiftUI showing an AdMob Interstitial breaks Navigation Flow
I have an app with a dashboard view, which when a user clicks on and item in the dashboard its suppose to navigate to the detailed view and the full screen as needs to show.
Now here is where the issue is, after the ad is shown the detailed view (child view) is viewable for a quick second and then the navigation goes back to the dashboard view (parent view).
Here is the code for my Admob:
class InterstitialAdsManager: NSObject, GADFullScreenContentDelegate, ObservableObject {

    @Published var interstitialAdLoaded: Bool = false

    var interstitialAd: GADInterstitialAd?

    let AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256032142544/xxxxxxxxx"

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func loadInterstitialAd() {
    
        GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: AD_UNIT_ID, request: GADRequest()) { [weak self] ad, error in
        
            guard let self = self else { return }
        
            if let error = error {
            
                print(": \(error.localizedDescription)")
                self.interstitialAdLoaded = false
            
                return
            
            }
        
            print(": Loading succeeded")
            self.interstitialAdLoaded = true
            self.interstitialAd = ad
            self.interstitialAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        
        }
    
    }

    func displayInterstitialAd(viewController: UIViewController) {

        let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController

        if let ad = interstitialAd {
        
            ad.present(fromRootViewController: root)
            self.interstitialAdLoaded = false
        
        } else {
        
            print(": Ad wasn't ready")
            self.interstitialAdLoaded = false
            self.loadInterstitialAd()
        
        }
    
    }

    func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {

        print(": Failed to display interstitial ad")
        self.loadInterstitialAd()
    
    }

    func adWillPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {

        print(": Displayed an interstitial ad")
        self.interstitialAdLoaded = false
    
    }

    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {

        print(": Interstitial ad closed")
    
    }

}

The code for the Dashboard going to the detailed view is pretty standard.
Does anyone know how i can resolve this and have the detailed view (child view) remain viewable and not go back all the way back to the dashboard (parent view)!?

Probably because you are using the rootViewController but it is impossible to tell since you havent provided any information about your Views.

What are my other options other than rootViewController!?

Interfacing with a UIViewController and a UIViewControllerRepresentable. SwiftUI uses the root for so many things.
